# Invalid runtime for JavaSE-19: The path points to a missing or inaccessible folder (/path/to/jdk-19)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How do I fix this runtime error in VSCODE 1.75.1? The JDK installed is jdk-19 in Windows C: location.

- settings.json

```
{
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
  
    {},
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-19",
      "path": "/path/to/jdk-19",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark Default",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "debug.onTaskErrors": "debugAnyway",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[c]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
  },
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
  "[cpp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
  },
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "workbench.view.alwaysShowHeaderActions": true,
  "zenMode.fullScreen": false,
  "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "on",
  "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19",
  "java.home": "c:\\Users\\Vindhya Sree\\.vscode\\Microsoft VS Code\\jdk-17"
}
```

I tried setting the environment variables and successfully set JAVA_HOME location as well. After doing that, I have this recurring problem of runtime errors.  I was using them normally as i installed the extension pack of Java from VSCODE itself and the previous version of JDK 17 but after a few months of programming with them, i got a message of updating the JDK to 17+ and configuring Java runtime as per the same and now after doing it all, it doesn't work on the same projects anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using two different jdk, keep both same and try.

"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "c:\Program Files\Java\**jdk-19**",

"java.home": "c:\Users\Vindhya Sree\.vscode\Microsoft VS Code\**jdk-17**"

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked and made my programming much easier on vscode.

Comment: Is "java.home" even a valid setting? I don't find it anywhere